# Non-bijective inverse functions

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, inverse-function

Playing with functions and their inverses, I noticed you cannot really obtain the *full* inverse of any surjective function.

The *full* inverse of an application $f\left(x\right) = y$ would be the function $g\left(y\right) = x$. Which is just impossible with any surjective applications. For instance, $f\left(x\right) = x^2$ has a *partial* inverse (in red) which is the square root function $g\left(y\right) = sqrt\left(x\right)$. But we lost all the negative inverse images.

[image: plot for f(x) and g(y)]

Same for the cardioid defined by $r\left(\theta\right) = 3-3\cos\left(\theta\right)$. We agree that $r\left(\theta\right)$ can take any values of $\theta + k2\pi$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So the radius will have the same **positive** value for $r\left(\frac{3}{4}\pi\right)$ and $r\left(\frac{5}{4}\pi\right)$ since the radius $r$ in polar coordinates cannot be negative.

So if we define (in red) the *partial* inverse $t(r) = \arccos\left(-\frac{r}{3}+1\right)$ and we plot it as we did for the square function, we notice that we get half of our cardioid, as angular images appear all on quadrant II. Again, we lost the angular inverse images on quadrant III.

[image: polar plot for r(t) and t(r)]

However, we can restore the values of any surjective application by just combining the inverse function and its opposite. So the injective inverse of $f\left(x\right)$ would be $\{g\left(y\right);-g\left(y\right)\}$, and the injective inverse of $r\left(\theta\right)$ would be $\{t\left(y\right);-t\left(y\right)\}$.

I need advices on my empirical approach, which may be incorrect.

Comment: You're onto a pretty nice generalization (of sorts) of inverse functions. Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image

Comment: @CameronWilliams I checked it out and it is the theoretical model for representing the ideal inverse function. However, I expected more of a practical explanation on how to obtain such inverse function, and in the special case of surjective function, how to enumerate the possible preimages.